# Writing a sum as a fraction

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, power-series

Express

$$\sum^{20}_{i=2}f(x)^i$$where $$f(x)=\sum_{i\geq 1}2^{i-1}x^{3i}$$ as a fraction of polynomials $p(x)/q(x)$ and simplify as much as possible.

Hmm. How to do it? Wolfram is really stupid on this one, just expanding the sum. Plugging into geometric series gives intractable mess.

Comment: $i \ge i$? :) Anyway, you should note that $2f(x) = \sum (2x^3)^i$ and use the geometric series sum to simplify the second expression. For simplifying the first expression, I think you'll get a second geometric series after finding the common denominator, which will come from the $i=20$ term.

Answer (score 1):

The sum of any geometric series is:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}r^k=\frac{1-r^n}{1-r}$$

Since your index starts at 2, you'll have to subtract the first two terms:

$$\sum_{k=2}^nr^k=\frac{1-r^n}{1-r}-r-1$$

Your $f(x)$ is an infinite series, so use the same equation to calculate the sum of the series. As long as $x^3<\frac{1}{2}$:
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^\infty{(2x^3)}^i=\frac{x^3}{1-2x^3}$$

The final result will be the geometric series from 1 to 20 with $r=f(x)$.

Comment: What is that last equation about? What is the right hand side? Amn't I supposed to effectively calculate 

$$\sum_{i=2}^{20}\left(\frac{x^{3}}{1-2x^{3}}\right)^{i}$$ or did I get get completely off the mark with simplifying $f(x)$?

Comment: @EricDong no, the last equation is $f(x)$. You have two different summations in your problem as stated: $f(x)$ is an infinite sum, and you want to find the sum from 2 to 20 of $f(x)$ to the $i$ power. I'll edit to clarify.

Comment: Hmm. It looks to me that $f(x)=\frac{x^3}{1-2x^3}$...

Comment: @EricDong ah, yes, you're correct, if the summation is starting from 1. Btw, I think you typo'd your summation, you have it as $\sum_{i\ge i}$.

Comment: My bad. sorry..

Comment: Also, I COMPLETELY get hwo to get $f(x)$. I don't get how to simplify the mess resulted in by plugging in. Even wolfram alpha fails to simplify the behemoth.

Comment: @EricDong You could simplify the expression to $\frac{r^2-r^n}{1-r}$, and then multiply the numerator and denominator by $(1-2x^3)^{20}$. Will your professor accept it if you leave it that way? It will be the ratio of two polynomials, it just won't be written general form. There's really no way to avoid it being a huge expression, since it's an 18th and 20th degree polynomial.

Comment: What is $n$ in your expression?

Comment: @EricDong $n$ is 20. I used $n$ instead just to show the general process.